# KVM Ubuntu Guest cannot connect to the internet on bridged networking

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, libvirt

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits) + KVM Host with 2 NICs:
 - eth0 connected to the "public" network
 -  eth1 connected to the br0 bridge with a private ip address range

From Host I can access internet, ping VM Guest and connect to it via SSH.
From VM Guest I can only ping Host, but cannot access Internet and cannot ping google.com

**Please help me with connecting VM Guest to the internet in the setup described below:**

---

### On Host:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.60
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.254
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bridge_ports    eth1
  bridge_stp      off
  bridge_maxwait  0
  bridge_fd       0

 # Create and destroy the bridge automatically.
pre-up brctl addbr br0
ip link set dev br0 up
post-up /usr/sbin/brctl setfd br0 0 addif br0 eth1
post-down brctl delbr br0
```

---

KVM Network is defined as:

```
<network>
<name>br0-net</name>
<uuid>9d24b473-0b4d-4cfa-8b12-7bf267d856ae</uuid>
<forward mode='bridge'/>
<bridge name='br0'/>
</network>
```

---

# sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

```
 net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

---

# route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

# iptables -t nat -vnL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

### On VM Guest:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.11
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

---

Guest xml is defined as

```
<interface type='bridge'>
<mac address='52:54:00:6b:93:69'/>
<source bridge='br0'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

---

# route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

# iptables -t nat -vnL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**Ping KVM Host from Guest does work for 10.0.0.1 and 192.168.2.60:**

$ ping 10.0.0.1

```
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.555 ms
```

$ ping 192.168.2.60

```
PING 192.168.2.60 (192.168.2.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.60: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.772 ms
```

**Ping a different computer 192.168.2.3 from Guest does not work:**

```
--- 192.168.2.3 ping statistics ---
277 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 276399ms
```

**Ping google.com from Guest does not work:**

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Comment: Show the problem you are having in the guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a iptable rule for the masquerade

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: This results in: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: that was a typo, i fixed the command

Comment: I have precisely the same issue as the OP.  However, I do not understand -- is this command on the guests or on the host?  What does that iptable rule do? Is there an equivalent in `ufw`?  Thanks!